# Get all users with certain birthdays

Tags: active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the MS Graph api to get the all users with specific birthdays.

For example, the users with birthdays on a specific day or within a specific week.

When I call:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email>/birthday`

I can get a birthday for a single user:

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('<email>')/birthday",
"value": "2018-06-07T00:00:00Z"
```

But the birthday property doesnt show up when I make a call to get all users

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/`

I can select some properties for all users with:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,givenName,postalCode`

but when I add birthday to that list I get the error:

```
    "code": "NotImplemented",
    "message": "This operation target is not yet supported.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "48d52783-3f0d-44ba-a8f2-15c24675a49f",
        "date": "2018-09-11T16:48:54"
    }
```

Is there an efficient way to do what I'm trying to do with graph explorer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no (for both Graph Explorer and your own app)

There is an existing feature request in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17463187-allow-retrieval-of-office-365-users-including-thei) similar to what you're asking for. I would recommend voting for that request so this gets the proper prioritization from the product team.